# Error to eject a function of a calculator in mysql

Tags: mysql, function

i don't know where is the error in the division because the operand is /. However, if i put the operand DIV, the execution is correct

```
delimiter /
create function calculadora (num1 int(25), num2 int(25), signo varchar (1)) returns decimal(25,2)
begin
    declare resultado decimal(25,2);
    if signo='+'
        then set resultado=num1+num2;
    elseif signo='-'
        then set resultado=num1-num2;
    elseif signo='*'
        then set resultado=num1*num2;
    elseif signo='/'
        then set resultado=num1/num2;
end if;
return resultado;
end/

select proveedores.calculadora(2, 5, '/');
```

Comment: Works for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qH2vEQskxfbEN3CoGx1JZc/0

Comment: It's because you're using `/` as the delimiter